# Auto compile SCSS files in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

Ok, here is what I want:

1. I write .scss files, not .sass files
2. On saving the file, I get the corresponding .css file in the same folder

Now there are plenty of SASS plugins on Sublime Text2 but none seems to provide anything beyond syntax highlighting for me.

Any suggestions on how to get auto-compiling working on Sublime Text2.

Comment: here [answer][1], to buils sass in sublime text 2 using Build system


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448546/sublime-text-2-doesnt-save-built-sass-file/30068537#30068537

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find any existing plugins that did this, so here it is:

Assuming you've installed the SCSS plugin from Package Control, you can save this as Packages/User/SCSS.py.

```py
import sublime_plugin
import subprocess
import os
from threading import Thread

def compile(input_file):
    output_file = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0] + ".css"
    cmd = "sass '{0}':'{1}'".format(input_file, output_file)
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

class SCSS(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    def on_post_save(self, view):
        scope = (view.syntax_name(view.sel()[0].b)).split().pop()
        if scope == "source.scss":
            input_file = view.file_name()
            t = Thread(target=compile, args=(input_file,))
            t.start()
```

Of course, this would be better as an official Package Control plugin with user configurable settings (where to save files, on/off, etc), but this meets your requirements and doesn't block the editor.

Comment: How will Sublime Text2 invoke this file?

Comment: For the sake of being explicit: It works. I tested it.

Sublime Text 2 parses all python files under its Packages directory. In this case, Sublime Text parses SCSS.py and the class defined in it inherits from sublime's EventListener class. Because it overrides the on_post_save method, Sublime will call that method after each save.

Here is the official documentation for the EventListener plugin class: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't work for me. My packages folder has the following: 1) SCSS Folder 2) Your SCSS.py file 3) A SCSS.pyc file.

Comment: Did you install the Package Control plugin, and is your syntax currently set to SCSS (shift+ctrl+p and type "Set Syntax: SCSS")? If yes and it's still not working, hit ctr+~ to bring up the ST console, then try saving the file again. There should be output in the console  explaining any errors. I can help you with the output.

Comment: Writing file /Users/rajat/Workspace/css/test.scss with encoding UTF-8
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: Required argument 'filename' (pos 2) not found

Comment: You're right! I fixed the code. Python threads and I aren't very good friends yet. Also, I fixed a bug where the output would get written to the wrong place if there were spaces in the path.

Comment: Doesn't work. `syntax_name` from ST2 has become `syntax_name` in ST3, but even then nothing's happening on save. No error message in the console.

When you say "Assuming you've installed the SCSS plugin from Package Control", which specific plugin are you talking about (there's a bunch of them with that name.) Finally, does it require a particular distribution of Sass?

Answer (score 5):

You should consider to use build system instead of dedicated plugin of it. It's very simple to do.

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html

Something like this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["sass","$file"],
  "selector": "source.scss",
  "path": "/usr/local/bin"
}
```

And just hit `ctrl + b` t build current file. If you have multiple builds for scss you can select one from build menu (`Tools -> Build Systems`).

Comment: I seem to remember that it's also possible to have this triggered "on save"

Comment: what is this path? what does it stands for?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [SublimeOnSaveBuild](https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild) plugin.
And in plugin filter settings just leave .scss files!
It's works for just great!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a sass/scss compiler plugin for Sublime Test, but I have my source folders separate from my css folders. So, going off the comments left on here I wrote SassBuilder that runs off a config file stored in your source folder. It has also been submitted to the Sublime Package Control repository. Once they pull the request, you can install it from there.

[SassBuilder on github](https://github.com/bnlucas/SassBuilder)

Answer (score 1):

Sass Builder is the new plugin which is available in Package Manager of sublime text.
This does not require any configuration. Just write your scss and hit cmd + b to compile.
Your css file will be generated in the same folder as scss.