# Sublime Text 2 doesn't save built SASS file

Tags: ruby, sass, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I installed [SASS build system for Sublime Text 2](https://github.com/jaumefontal/SASS-Build-SublimeText2) just as described in the readme and everything succeeded (also SASS installation). Now, if I try to build my .scss file ST2 prints out something like "[Finished in 0.2s]" without showing me any result or save a .css file. I also can write some wrong code and it will not complain about it, just give me a "finished" message again. Any idea what's causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Mountain Lion.
I fixed it by changing the "cmd" line in the SASS.sublime-build (and all the others build files I have for SASS) from

```
["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/${file_base_name}.css"]
```

to

```
["sass --update $file:${file_path}/${file_base_name}.css"]
```

Don't know why, but practically if you write the command in an array with more than one item, it won't work, while the command all in one string does work.

Comment: However you came to try this out - it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

gem install sass

in ST2 /tools/build system/new build system...

```
{
  "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "sass --style compressed", "$file", "$file_base_name.css.min"]
}
```

or

```
{
  "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "sass", "$file", "$file_base_name.css"]
}
```

save as "sass.sublime-build"