# Rails app with Compass css files

Tags: compass-sass

I have a very basic rails application in which I've added compass and zurb foundation to.  I've noticed an issue that now when I save changes to any stylesheet, which I'm using scss for, I also have an additional css file with the same name but .css instead of .scss added to the stylesheets directory.  This causes a problem because my layout templates then try to use the application.css file instead of the application.scss file.

Has anyone had this happen and how can I get it to stop adding .css files to my stylesheets directory?

In my foundation_and_overrides.scss file the content is the standard zurb foundation content.

However, in the foundation_and_overrides.css file the contents are:

https://gist.github.com/iambca/5084463

Comment: `.scss` gets compiled to `css`. the `css` file is the one your application will use, `scss` is just there for coding convenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue here: [Auto compile SCSS files in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901067/auto-compile-scss-files-in-sublime-text-2)

I still don't have a solution but this is the issue.  Sublime Text 3 is coming so perhaps this will be resolved in the new release.